# Shapekeys - how to smooth out mesh wrinkles?

Tags: animation, mesh, topology, shape-keys

Ok, Im a noob with shape keys and am having some trouble with "wrinkles" that show up on the mesh (really only when rendered w/ lighting) that are painstaking/impossible to try to get rid of just going into edit mode with the shape key on.

Basically, this is the winkled shapely in edit mode:

[image]

Wrinkles when rendered:

[image]

These were caused because I used an armature to position the mouth initially, and at first this mouth was wide open.Joining the faces in edit mode makes this even worse.. how can I fix this?

Comment: I can't seem to identify the wrinkles. Can you mark them on you image? I'd also advise you to read a topology guide.

Comment: They're pretty clear - See how his face has all the lines going away from the mouth? Those shouldn't be there.